# Metric to use to choose between different models - Hyperparameters tuning

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, hyperparameter-tuning, metric

I'm building a Feedforward Neural Network with Pytorch and doing hyperparameters tuning using Ray Tune. I have train, validation and test set, train and validation used during the training procedure.
I have different versions of the model (different learning rates and numbers of neurons in the hidden layers) and I have to choose the best model. But I'm unsure on which metric should I use to choose the best model. Basically I don't know the XXXX in this line of code:

```
analysis.get_best_config(metric='XXXX', mode='min')
```

Should it be test loss or validation loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, the function of your `testset` is to evaluate the performance of your model on new data. It mimics the situation of your model being put into production. The `validation set` is used for optimizing your algorithm.

Personally I would recommend tuning your algorithm using your `validation set` and using the hyperparameters of the training epoch with the lowest **validation loss**. The accuracy of the model using these hyperparameters on your `testset` can be used to estimate the performance of your model in the 'real world'.

Comment: Thanks! So testset used only when I have the completed model with all his hyperparameters defined